# In CloudFormation, does "A DependsOn B" ensure that A is deleted before B?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

We are using CloudFormation to set up a role and a policy for it. The policy is set to depend on the role using the "DependsOn" property like so:

Role definition:

```
"LambdaExecutionRole": {
  "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
  "Properties": {
  [...]
```

Policy definition:

```
"lambdaexecutionpolicy": {
  "DependsOn": [
    "LambdaExecutionRole"
  ],
  "Roles": [
    {
      "Ref": "LambdaExecutionRole"
    }
  ],
  [...]
```

From the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html), I understand that this DependsOn relation between the two entities should ensure that the policy is always deleted before the role.

> Resource A is deleted before resource B.

However, we encounter an error where it appears that the system tries to delete the role before the policy:

```
Resource Name: [...] (AWS::IAM::Role)
Event Type: delete
Reason: Cannot delete entity, must delete policies first. (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 409; Error Code: DeleteConflict; Request ID: [...]; Proxy: null)
```

I'm not sure how that's even possible, as I would have considered the "A  DependsOn B" to ensure that the system never tries to delete B before deleting A. Is my understanding wrong here? Can there be a situation where the system tries to delete B before A?

And yes, I understand that in this case the obvious solution is to use an inline policy, as the policy is only used for this specific role. But as this behavior seems to conflict with my intuitive understanding of the official documentation, I want to properly understand what the "DependsOn" property actually means.

Comment: Did you add the explicit `DependsOn` to solve an actual problem?  I don't recall ever explicitly setting a dependency for Role-Policy relationships.  A quick glance at a couple CDK-generated Cfn templates show no such `DependsOn` between Roles and Policies.  I belive Cfn infers the dependency because the policy has a reference to the role.  Perhaps instead of helping, the explicit `DependsOn` is creating a circular dependency or otherwise interfering?

Comment: I believe the `DependsOn` was auto-generated by Amplify, though I may be wrong on this. Yes, I believe it should be unnecessary, as we have other places in the code where no `DependsOn` is used. However, specifying something that is already implicitly set should not lead to a different behavior in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**  Unable to replicate the error.  `DependsOn` does not seem to be the culprit.

I used the CDK to create two versions of a minimum test stack with only two resources, `AWS::IAM::Role` and `AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy`.  V1 had no explicit policy dependency set on the role. V2, like the OP, did.  The difference made no difference. Both versions deployed and were destroyed without error.

**Version 1: CDK-Generated Default:**  no 'depends on' in the template

**Version 2 (as in OP)**: has explicit dependency - Policy depends on the Role.  The CDK added one line to the template: `"DependsOn": [ "TestRole6C9272DF" ]` under `"TestPolicyCC05E598"`

The two versions differed only by that single `DependsOn`. Both versions deployed and destroyed as expected without error.

```json
// resource section of CDK-generated Cloud Formation Template
"Resources": {
  "TestRole6C9272DF": {
    "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
    "Properties": {
      "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
        "Statement": [
          {
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
              "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
            }
          }
        ],
        "Version": "2012-10-17"
      }
    },
    "Metadata": {
      "aws:cdk:path": "TsCdkPlaygroundIamDependencyStack/TestRole/Resource"
    }
  },
  "TestPolicyCC05E598": {
    "Type": "AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy",
    "Properties": {
      "PolicyDocument": {
        "Statement": [
          {
            "Action": [
              "logs:CreateLogGroup",
              "logs:CreateLogStream",
              "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
          }
        ],
        "Version": "2012-10-17"
      },
      "Description": "",
      "Path": "/",
      "Roles": [
        {
          "Ref": "TestRole6C9272DF"
        }
      ]
    },
    "DependsOn": [
      "TestRole6C9272DF"  // <-- The difference that makes no difference
    ],
    "Metadata": {
      "aws:cdk:path": "TsCdkPlaygroundIamDependencyStack/TestPolicy/Resource"
    }
  },
```